# Databinding to TextBox - setting Text property in code doesn't update model

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I am working on some data collection forms in WinForms/C#.  When the form loads, I am looping through a configuration and adding a new Binding to each of the TextBox controls; mapping the Text property of each TextBox control to specific string property on my POCO object.

```
public void BindTextBoxControls(dynamic entity, List<TextBoxConfig> textBoxConfig)
{
    foreach (var config in textBoxConfig)
        config.Control.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", entity, config.PropertyName));
}
```

Everything has been working as expected, new records properly saving new values entered into the corresponding TextBox controls, TextBoxes populating with the correct values when reopened a previously entered records with the form, and updates to values in TextBoxes of previously entered records are getting the updated values set on the underlying POCO.

However, I started to layer in some business rules onto the form specifically to gray out/disable and clear out previously entered values in the TextBox based on other user input/activity on the form - things are not working as expected.

In a contrived example; a rule like if a Checkbox_1 is checked then TextBox #5 should not be valued (clear out any previously entered value and disable it from input).  On my Checkbox_1 event handler for CheckedChanged, I specifically check if the Checkbox_1 is checked and if so, set TextBox_1.Text == null and TextBox_1.Enabled = false.  This works as expected and on the form, I see any previously entered value cleared from the TextBox_1 and it becomes enabled.

```
    private void chkCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!chkCheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            txtBox5.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

However, when I debug and break on the save and inspect the underlying POCO's property that the underlying control is bound to after the method is called; the old value still persists on the object's property which the text box is bound to, despite the textbox having not value appearing on the form.  When I reopen the form for that record, the old cleared out value is re-populated in the disabled TextBox.  However, manually clearing out the value in the same TextBox or updating a value and inspecting the object shows the updated value after those operations are performed.

It seems like changing the Text value of a TextBox control (e.g. the Text property of a TextBox) in code maybe somehow be "bypassing" the DataBinding?  I'm actually seeing the same/similar behavior when applying similar rules to "uncheck" TextBoxes programmatically within event handler methods - the CheckBox controls are also using DataBinding to boolean properties on the POCO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup databinding by this overload: [`Binding(String, Object, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.-ctor?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System_Windows_Forms_Binding__ctor_System_String_System_Object_System_String_), then the value of [`DataSourceUpdateMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) will be [`OnValidation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), which means when you modify the value of control's property using code or through UI, the binding will push the new value to data source only after `Validating` event happens for the control.

To fix the problem, use either of the following options:

- Use another overload and set the `DataSourceUpdateMode` to `OnProperetyChanged`
- *OR*, after setting the Value of the `TextBox.Text` call [`ValidateChildren`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.validatechildren?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method of the form.

**Example - Set the DataSourceUpdateMode to OnProperetyChanged**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LegalCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsRealPerson { get; set; }
}
Person person;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person = new Person() { 
        Name = "My Company", LegalCode = "1234567890", IsRealPerson = false };

    NameTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), person,
        nameof(Person.Name), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    LegalCodeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(TextBox.Text), person, 
        nameof(Person.LegalCode), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    IsRealPersonCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(nameof(CheckBox.Checked), person, 
        nameof(Person.IsRealPerson), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    IsRealPersonCheckBox.CheckedChanged += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (IsRealPersonCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            LegalCodeTextBox.Text = null;
            LegalCodeTextBox.Enabled = false;
        }
    };
}
```

**Note - You can put the logic inside the model**

Another solution (Which needs more effort and more changes in your code) is implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in your model class. Then when `PropertyChanged` event raises for your boolean property, you can check if it's false then you can set the string property to null.

In this approach you don't need to handle UI events. Also right after updating the model property, the UI will be updated; in fact implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` enables two-way databinding for your model class.